# Mysql fetch rows limited by another table column value

Tags: mysql

I have list of products and seller who added this products
Each Seller has a limit to show the products.
I need to write a query to list all the products with pagination 100 and show only seller products limited to that seller

```
`Seller Table`
| seller id| Seller Name |  limit |
|:-------- |:-----------:| ------:|
| 1        | Seller One  | 1     |
| 2        | Seller Two  | 3    |
| 3        | Seller Three| 2    |

`Products Table
| product id| seller id | Product Name |
|:-------- |:----------:| ------------:|
| 1        | 1          | Product 1    |
| 2        | 2          | Product 2    |
| 3        | 1          | Product 3    |
| 4        | 1          | Product 4    |
| 5        | 2          | Product 5    |
| 6        | 2          | Product 6    |
| 7        | 2          | Product 7    |
| 8        | 3          | Product 8    |
| 9        | 3          | Product 9    |
| 9        | 3          | Product 10   |
| 9        | 3          | Product 11   |

(Output or Result I am expecting)
| product id| seller id | Product Name |
|:-------- |:----------:| ------------:|
| 1        | 1          | Product 1    |
| 2        | 2          | Product 2    |
| 5        | 2          | Product 5    |
| 6        | 2          | Product 6    |
| 8        | 3          | Product 8    |
| 9        | 3          | Product 9    |
```

Seller 1 = Product 1

Seller 2 = Product 2 , Product 5 and Product 6

Seller 3 = Product 8 and  Product 9

I want to get this products

How do I write a query?

and also is it possible to selected random products of the seller

I have query only to fetch only the products.

````
$products = Products::paginate(100);
```

I need modify it based on Seller Model
````

Comment: provide some reference code you have tried so far

Comment: Send the code please

Comment: Whats the difference between Products Table and List Products??

Comment: @BurhanKashour List Products  is the Output I want.

Comment: @DeveloperLaravel  I have added product query

Comment: try with this : `Product::whereIn('seller_id', Seller::pluck('id'))->paginate(100);`

Comment: @BLPraveen is product_id unique in product table? If so why 9 multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable WHERE clause when searching particular seller and product otherwise disable it. Use LIMIT and OFFSET for pagination. Please try this

```
-- MySQL (v5.8)
SELECT t.product_id, s.seller_id, t.product_name
FROM seller s
INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id
                 , seller_id
                 , product_name
                 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seller_id ORDER BY product_id) row_num
            FROM Products
            -- WHERE seller_id = 1
            -- AND product_id = 1
           ) t
      ON s.seller_id = t.seller_id
     AND t.row_num <= s.t_limit;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d142f50fb24763ec9fc1e937f8b8d6a7

If needed comma separated product_name then try this one

```
SELECT  CONCAT(MAX(s.seller_name), ' = ', GROUP_CONCAT(t.product_name)) expected_output
FROM seller s
INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id
                 , seller_id
                 , product_name
                 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seller_id ORDER BY product_id) row_num
            FROM Products
            -- WHERE seller_id = 1
            -- AND product_id = 1
           ) t
      ON s.seller_id = t.seller_id
     AND t.row_num <= s.t_limit
GROUP BY s.seller_id;
```

Please check from https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e4cfa7dbb744e7aa416b79d6f964775

Comment: it is working. Thanks helping me. it got solved

Comment: Can you help me with Laravel query

Comment: welcome @BLPraveen. Sorry I don't work with Laravel query. If I'm familiar with laravel then surely help you.

Comment: Anyway thanks. I completed it. Your solution worked

Comment: Rahul is it possible to get latest first descending order

Comment: use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seller_id ORDER BY product_id DESC) row_num

Answer (score 1):

As per @RahulBiswas sql code  I wrote a Laravel Query. It is working

```
 $subq  = Products::select(DB::raw('ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seller_id ORDER BY id) row_num, *'));
                 $query = Sellers::select('t.*',)->join(\DB::raw('('.$subq->toSql().') as t'), function ($join) use ($subq) { 
                            $join->on('sellers.user_id','t.seller_id')
                            $join->on('t.row_num', '<=', "sellers.limit")
                        })
```